# db table or text files for stream content

Tags: sql-server-2008, api, streaming, twitter

I am consuming data from a streaming API with large volume and was wondering which would be the more appropriate option to store the content temp before processing. It seems the table would be a better way to manage the content but which would be faster so as not to lose time during the stream connection.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is truly your only concern, you should go with a filesystem approach. All things being equal, pulling data from a file is faster vs pulling a BLOB from the database. Realistically, there's probably more involved in your requirements than pure speed so I'd read up on the [pros and cons of each approach](https://blogs.oracle.com/manveen/entry/blob_vs_file_system_storage). Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, the DB approach might end up being the way to go.

Comment: I considered a db cause it would be easier to put each entry as one record whereas with a file I have to parse the file and run the risk of losing an entry. But thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean since I've got pretty sparse details on what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: I have a full stream where I am consuming data from and at times I will  get disconnected because I am not reading data fast enough. The issues is that I append the data to stringbuilder and once it reaches a max size write it to a text file. I am concerned that if wait for the stream to end I will end up with buffer issues or something.

Comment: when your StringBuilder is ready to be written to file/db I would fork off a thread to deal with persistence so that your application doesnt have to wait for it to finish. Start a new StringBuilder and let the old one get written to file/db in the background. Loop that process and as long as you can write faster than your stream is streaming you should be fine.